# Split a string in shell to get all fields upto final '.' (Bash)

Tags: string, bash

I'm looking to get 1.2.3.4 of string 1.2.3.4.5
I know that I can use this code to get the final number, but what can I use to get all numbers previous. (Including ':')

```
$ foo=1.2.3.4.5
$ c_num=`echo ${foo##*.}`
$ echo $c_num
$ 5
```

I have tried using IFS.

```
$ IFS='.' read -ra STRING <<< "$foo"
$ u_num="${STRING[0]}"'.'"${STRING[1]}"'.'"${STRING[2]}"'.'"${STRING[3]}"
$ echo $u_num
$ 1 2 3 4
# It should have returned 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Yes, this is being used in a pure bash shell script.

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of the second example? If `foo` is `1.2.3.4.5`, how is it that you want `1.2.6` as a result?

Comment: As you can see the 1 2 3 4 are all going into an array, but my variable u_num only needs the first 2. I'll edit the code to make it all four.

Comment: Why are you using `:` ?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, updated.

Comment: `c_num=${foo:0:1}; echo ${foo:0:3}"."$((c_num +5))` is this what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
echo ${foo%.*}
```

Yielding:

```
foo="1.2.3.4.5"
echo ${foo%.*}
1.2.3.4
```

and

```
foo="1 2 6"
echo ${foo%.*}
```

yields

```
1 2 6
```

If you want to convert the spaces to `.`, you can use `tr`:

```
echo $foo | tr ' ' '.'
```

Yielding the following for `foo="1 2 6"`

```
1.2.6
```

Comment: this also returns '1 2 3'

Comment: @RussellHickey it works for me with bash under Debian. Are you sure you are using bash ? what is your shebang ?

Comment: @RussellHickey I'm not sure I understand your comment. What exactly yields `1 2 3`? Maybe your second example in the problem statement needs clarification.

Comment: @lurker my code splits the data into an array, which I then put into a variable, "$v1'.'$v2'.'$v3" <-- i'm trying to put a '.' between them but yet they're returning simply as "$v1 $v2 $v3"

Comment: @RussellHickey could you then just use `tr`? E.g., `echo $foo | tr ' ' '.'`?

Comment: That has worked thank you. If you add the `tr` bit to your answer I will accept it. Thank You.

Comment: @RussellHickey You can't accept a solution involving `tr` as you specifically asked for _Bash only_.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf i'm using #!/bin/bash and it worked?

Comment: @RussellHickey `tr` is an external command to Bash, not a builtin. Usually, when we mention _Bash Only_ (or pure Bash), we disregard all external commands and only want builtins. Type `help` to have a list of all builtins and keywords; you'll see that `tr` is not in the list.

Comment: my apologies I didn't know this. Thanks for the info.